# Using fold to sum all ASCII values of characters in a list OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement "List.fold_left" to compute the ASCII values of each character in a list (e.g ['a';'b';'A']) and then add them up.

```
let ascii_sum lst = List.fold_left (fun elem acc -> Char.code(elem) + ... ) 0 lst
```

In the "...' of my code, I was thinking of a way to move on to the next element of my accumulator, compute its ASCII value and then add its value to the current Char.code(elem). I may not understand how to implement fold_left correctly, especially I am not quite sure to understand what (fun ...) is in Ocaml, so any input from you will be helpful for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of a way to move on to the next element of my accumulator.

This is where you got it wrong. You don't need to do that because `fold_left` will do it for you.

See the accumulator (the `acc` variable in your anonymous function) as an intermediary result. Look at this example:

```
List.fold_left (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0 [1;2;3]
```

It adds up the elements in the list `[1;2;3]`, but here is how it actually does that:

[image: Fold example diagram]

(I hope the diagram makes sense, I drew that off the top of my head.)

All you have to figure out is the actual function that will return the correct intermediary result.

> **Quick tip**: Be careful about your types. In my example, the result has the same type than the elements of the list, which is not your case.
>
> **Quick tip 2**: Another approach is to use `List.map` to compute all the ASCII values of your characters, and then add them all up.

---

As per the comments, here is the same diagram, but using your actual problem. The only thing you have left to do is figure out what to do inside the function.

I know it can be frustrating, but once you get the hang of it, you will see that it's very simple in fact.

[image: Fold example updated diagram]

Comment: I want to practice on fold so I will stick to fold at the moment. I think the type of my accumulator is an integer because at any point of the process, I want an integer which is the sum of all ASCII values of characters in the list. I am stuck at developing the "fun(...)".

Comment: You will use `fold` in any case, even if you follow my quick tip 2. If you don't want to use `map`, then your `fold` function must do two things : 1) find the ASCII code of the `elem` parameter; 2) add this value to `acc`. I'll update my answer to help you a bit more without giving you the solution. :)

Comment: @JohnDunn: Were you able find the solution? If so, I'll add it to my answer for future reference. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something that looks like this:

```
(fun arg1 arg2 -> expression)
```

is a function. It takes two arguments (arg1 and arg2) and returns the value of the expression.

Here's an example:

```
# (fun a b -> a * b) 17 3;;
- : int = 51
```

This function multiplies the two parameters and returns the result.

The type of `List.fold_left` is like this:

```
('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

The first parameter of type `'a -> 'b -> 'a` is the function that accumulates the desired answer. Note that the accumulator is the first parameter and the second parameter is one element of the list.

If you look at your function you'll see you have the parameters backwards.

Once you're comfortable with the basic structure (as shown by the type), it's not hard to write an accumulator function. In your case you just want to return the new sum. You have everything you need for this, you just need to plug it all together.

Comment: I am confused because when I write another function called "reverse", which reverses the order of elements in my list : say rev [1;2;3;4] will give me a list [4;3;2;1] and my function is List.fold_left  (fun elem acc -> acc::element) [] lst. This says the element goes first and then the accumulator goes in the second. But in your response above, you said my function in ascii has the parameters in backwards. Why is that?

Comment: Your names are backwards, that's all. The `::` operator takes an element at the left and a list at the right. So your names are reversed.